# How much gelatine to use instead of xanthan or guar gum in ice cream

Tags: substitutions, ice-cream, gelatin, xanthan

I bought a Cuisinart ICE-30BC ice cream machine and I am experimenting with it. Some ice cream and gelato recipes ask for xanthan gum.

I can't find any of it in my county, but I read that I can replace it with powdered gelatin.

My question is, if a recipe calls for 3g of xanthan gum, how much gelatin should I use to replace it?? Is it less or more?

Comment: I don't believe that gelatin is a suitable thickener for use in ice cream/sorbet, so unless the *place you read that* has some data on use *in frozen confections,* I'd suggest using something else, or just skipping it (or using recipes that don't ask for it, which is probably a better way to skip it, as those will have some other thickening in play, such as a custard.)

Comment: Exactly I will skip the gelatin part, but I think the ice crystals  came from the skin of fruits because I didn't strain them at all. I just blended them and throw them into the machine

Comment: what country are you from? happy to send over some xanthan gum!

Comment: I am from Lebanon

Answer (score 1):

Gelatin is fine for a stabilizer it was used a lot in ice cream back in the day. Not sure the percentage to use but using a higher bloom strength could be recommend 200-250. Maybe start off using .005 of mix for a starting point and -+ after that for what you want.

Answer (score -1):

[This link](https://www.leaf.tv/articles/how-to-use-xanthan-gum-to-replace-gelatin/) suggests to use 1/2 amount of xanthan gum for 1 amount of gelatine

so, 1/2 xanthan = 1 gelatine

so, for 3g xanthan you should be using 6g of gelatine

Comment: Sorry, this link is for something entirely different. It addresses the substitution the other way round, and it is not meant for ice cream. I hate it to place a downvote on somebody's first participation on our site, and on a personal level, I apologize for that. But the advice you give is factually wrong, and it is quite likely that it will fail.